# MenuItem.OnMenuItemClickListener not working when second click

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-studio, onclick

I created fragment and arrange its visibilty based onclick event of menu item. When i click first, it works properly but click again fragment visibility not hide. Explanation of image; When i click settings gray fragment is showing, when click again i want to hide gray fragment but it is not doing this stuff.

[image]

Here is my code;

```
   @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
     MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.action_settings);
    item.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new MenuItem.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
            if (findViewById(R.id.frameLayout) != null)
            {
                FragmentTest fragmenttest = new FragmentTest();
                FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
                if (fragmenttest.isVisible()) {
                    ft.hide(fragmenttest);

                } else {


                    if (fragmenttest.isAdded()) {

                    } else {
                        ft.add(R.id.frameLayout, fragmenttest, "Hello Fragment");
                    }

                    ft.show(fragmenttest);

                }
                ft.commit();

            }
            return false;
        }
    });
    return true;


}
```

Comment: i would suggest rather than writing this complex logic write simple logic of counter

take one counter variable initialise it with 0

take mod of 2 of counter variable i.e

if(count%2==0)
{
visible logic
}
else
{
invisible logic
}

Comment: what about overriding `onOptionsItemSelected` http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onOptionsItemSelected(android.view.MenuItem) ?

Comment: @It has done again. My problem causes about declaring Fragment inside if statement. After move code inside onoptionsitemselected it works again :) Thank you. I will use onoptionsitemselected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

move

`FragmentTest fragmenttest = new FragmentTest();`

to the top of activity.

Comment: the reason is "every fragment should be related with an activity"